# VS Code c++: program finds directory when compiling but "No such file or directory" when running

Tags: c++, eigen3

Complete beginner to VS Code here - I'm trying to get to grips with Eigen with a simple code and I get this error when I run my program:

```
PS C:\PATH\Eigen Testing> cd "c:\PATH\Eigen Testing\" ; if ($?) { g++ EigenTEST01.cpp -o EigenTEST01 } ; if ($?) { .\EigenTEST01 }
EigenTEST01.cpp:2:23: fatal error: Eigen/Dense: No such file or directory
 #include <Eigen/Dense>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
```

The program compiles with no errors though, and I can run it with `.\EigenTEST01.exe` in the terminal just fine. I can't work out why I can't run it using the VS Code run code command as usual. Any suggestions appreciated

My task.json file is:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-IC:/cppTools/eigen-3.4.0/"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

and my c_cpp_properties.json is:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${default}",
                "C:/cppTools/eigen-3.4.0/"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x86",
            "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

The program itself is a simple Hello World script:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>


int main(){

    std::cout << "And we go again..." << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `g++ EigenTEST01.cpp -o EigenTEST01` looks like running some another but not `cppbuild` task with the command "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe".

Comment: Make sure you are not using code-runner. Also you did not follow the official VSCode instructions: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: So code-runner was the problem and I am not familiar enough with it to try and fix it, so I've just disabled it and accepted the slightly different workflow...